# undefined method `jobs' for nil:NilClass in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Please Guys, i need help solving this problem. I was trying to get jobs/new .From my rails console;

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `jobs' for nil:NilClass:
  app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:17:in `new'
```

### routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :jobs
  devise_for :users
    resources :home
    root 'jobs#index'
  end
```

### jobs_controller.rb

```
 # GET /jobs/new
  def new
    @job = current_user.jobs.build
  end

  # POST /jobs
  # POST /jobs.json
  def create
    @job = current_user.jobs.build(job_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.save
        format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @job }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Just check if `current_user` is being initialized before those actions (new, create) are executed.

Comment: @SebastianPalma thanks, but i think i need help with that.can you please

Comment: Put a `byebug` or `binding.pry` (in case you're using pry) right before any current_user.jobs call and proceed executing that action, check the rails server then.

Comment: Thank You @SebastianPalma. I did not add  before_action :authenticate_user! in the jobs_controller. I added it and its now working

Comment: That's great. Don't forget you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I did not add before_action :authenticate_user! in the jobs_controller.

I added it and it's now working:

```
# jobs_controller
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  # stuffs
  def method
  end

  def method
  end
end
```